# Deploy firebase cloud functions - Invalid function service account

Tags: firebase, deployment, google-cloud-functions

I am trying to deploy my firebase cloud functions they work fine on local host but when I try to deploy them I get the following error:

{"@type":"type.googleapis.com/google.cloud.audit.AuditLog","status":{"code":3,"message":"Invalid function service account requested: default. Please visit https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/troubleshooting for in-depth troubleshooting documentation."},"authenticationInfo":

I tried to play with roles but nothing works any help

Comment: I'm having the same error and I don't know why. Although it was working correctly earlier!

Comment: I think i've found some kind of a temporary solution for this. You can check this https://github.com/firebase/firebase-tools/issues/4697#issuecomment-1172733975

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Okay so the main problem is in the **11.2.0** version of `firebase-tools`.
The steps i did to reproduce was simply downgrading to the **11.1.0** version and it worked perfectly!
This is the [issue](https://github.com/firebase/firebase-tools/issues/4697) on github and this is the solution suggested by [mhotan](https://github.com/mhotan):

```
npm install -g firebase-tools@11.1.0
```

Comment: Thank you, downgrading to 11.1.0 version worked for me too.

Comment: Same problem here with 11.2.0
Downgrading to 11.1.0 worked for me